# Foreign Key Reference for Django in Admin

Tags: django, python-3.4

I have been trying to solve this issue in Django admin but still cannot find the documentation.

In my **models.py**, I have the following code:

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  author = models.ForeignKey('Author', blank=False)

class Author(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField('First Name',max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=50, blank=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return (self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
```

and in **admin.py**
from django.contrib import admin

```
# Register your models here.
from .models import Author, Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ['title', 'author', 'get_author_description']

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

However, every time I run the server, I have been getting the error

```
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of         
'list_display[2]' refers to 'get_author_description', which is not a 
callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 
'blog.Post'.
```

I have been reading a lot of documentation about this but still to no avail. Any takers?

**FINAL EDIT**
I have decided to keep the initial post with the question. The final solution only involves the change in `PostAdmin`.

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'author_description',]

    def author_description(self, obj):
        return obj.author.description
        author_description.short_description = 'The Author Description'
```

The key things to take note of are:

- The method `author_description` needs to be in the same indentation as the class. Also, it needs to return `obj.author.description` as we are referring to the author object. `get_author_description` is not required at all (you can say it was a distraction).

Comment: What is `get_author_description`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a custom method in the admin class as:

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'author_description']

    def author_description(self, obj):
        return obj.author.get_author_description()
```

Additionally, you can custom format a field or a property within the custom method. If the method would return HTML, you could add the following, after the method, in the class:

```
author_description.allow_tags = True
```

Last, if you would like to add a custom verbose name for this method:

```
author_description.short_description = "My awesome name"
```

Comment: Hmm, I added the lines and it is still throwing me the error. Am I doing something wrong?
<class 'blog.admin.PostAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[2]' refers to 'author_description', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'PostAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'blog.Post'.

Comment: Post Edited. Please read and update your code. `author_description` was not correctly indented.

Comment: I got it! I will make changes to the post to make it all clear. It all makes sense now, @LuisMasuelli. The `author_description` should be a `def` within the `PostAdmin` class or it will not be able to identify the method. I shall add one more thing. The last line should be `return obj.author.get_author_description()` because the description is in the `Author` class, not the `Post`. I caught it during running the server.

Comment: @bryansis2010 having get_author_description as a method name in author seems to violate DRY

Comment: Agree with you @Foon, I will take that into account when drafting the edited answer.

Comment: how can i make sure these fields can be referenced in the queryset for an admin action